# jQuery ui datepicker not opening on focus when using icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

In the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger) it says:

> *Click the icon next to the input field to show the datepicker. Set the datepicker to open on focus (default behavior), on icon click, or both.*

However clicking on the input field when using an icon trigger does not appear to open the datepicker.

In the interests of good usability I would like to give the user the choice of either clicking the input or the icon.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out there is a simple way to achieve this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ showOn: "both", buttonImage: "/images/calendar.png", buttonImageOnly: true });
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showOn

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an "onfocus" event to your textbox and then in that javascript event do a datapicker.show();

```
<input type="text" onfocus="javascript:showBox();" name="box1" />

<script>
   function showBox() {
     $("#datepicker").show();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. In my case I have many datepickers on the ones page. With your solution I'm guessing I would have to create seperate functions to deal with each separate datepicker. I was hoping that I have missed something in the docs, especially as the introduction text seems to imply this functionality already exists? Thanks for your answer though :)